# Loading Apple APNs auth key to Java PrivateKey

Tags: java, encryption, apple-push-notifications

### Problem

I'm having difficulties loading **APN's auth key** to **Java**. My understanding is that Java can read PKCS8 encoded private keys but I get an exception.

**Exception I get using Bouncy Castle (bcprov-jdk15on-1.55)**

```
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.ExtendedInvalidKeySpecException: unable to process key spec: java.io.IOException: algorithm identifier 1.2.840.10045.2.1 in key not recognised
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:366)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: algorithm identifier 1.2.840.10045.2.1 in key not recognised
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

**Exception I get using Java (jdk1.8.0_74)**

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:217)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.parseKeyBits(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:206)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:342)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:356)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:91)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:75)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:316)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:213)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Version must be 0
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.parseKeyBits(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:192)
    ... 34 more
```

### Implementation

I have tried using both Java and bouncycastle provider:

```
byte[] pkcs8EncodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(APNS_PRIVATE_KEY);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedKey));
```

I've created a sample project: [http://tutorialpoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZFJOOGMzajMxUGc)

### Here is the test key

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg9eWdXw19hL94+Jx1xjb79Y3Hr9rAaRYaoe4XSv6BnPigCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAR9VOiSABvXFHeq/hCMEx63Vq0mYneI2aqQu5sLu5x8DrzUd82BodKoUG3dMPWY9m86dGYAR9xhVUlBDpap9TfH
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution

Basically apple does not use RSA algorithm, but rather ECC (Elliptic curve cryptography) so I have to use **`EC`** algorithm when loading private key.

http://rahulatjava.blogspot.si/2014/02/elliptical-curve-cryptography-in-java.html

### Working version

```java
byte[] pkcs8EncodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(APNS_PRIVATE_KEY);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedKey));
```

Comment: You really should avoid explicitly specifying the provider unless you need the specific implementation from that provider. Registered providers are automatically searched in a reasonable order and the first one that claims to provide the algorithm is selected. In other words, you should use `KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")`.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that. I have changed the answer to reflect this.